# Losing hard disk space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

On my C:\ drive, the installed software takes only 3.3GB of space. The total drive space is 30GB. I do not have any restore points, nothing in my recycle bin, but still I only have 1.54GB of free space. I have even tried to "Free up disk space", ***(Control Panel\System and Security\Free up disk space)***, but still nothing. Where does the rest go to? I really need it back. Please help.

I'm on windows 7. My antivirus is 360 Total Security.

Answer (score 1):

Run TreeSize (free or trial) as admin. Don't remove anything (especially not the winsxs folder) unless you're very sure it won't do harm.

http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/

Answer (score 0):

The C:\ drive is also where Windows itself is installed and that alone is usually taking up 20 GB or more of diskspace. On my machine here it is already 30 GB, but it tends to grow over time with every windows update...

Add to that, that the C: drive is also the default location for the User directories, where almost every programm is dumping their configuration. It is the default location for documents, pictures, music etc. and the location for the temp directory that is used heavily.

And the location for the swap file is also on the C: drive if you didn't change it to somewhere else.

So there is not much you can do about a full C: drive this small, I would recommend to try to increase its size to atleast a 100 GB, more if you can spare the space. Also try avoid using the C: drive as location to install programms. Unfortunately all the installers out there default to the C: drive, so it is a bit of a hassle to have to change it every time. But it will help you in the long run by avoiding conflicts with your Windows installation.